# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

Tags: java, arraylist

Like the title says, my problem is that when I compile I get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1. Here is the part where the problem is coming from.

Edit.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1   
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)   
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)  
at pa6.FlightFinder.bestDirectPrice(FlightFinder.java:117)  
at pa6.FlightFinder.main(FlightFinder.java:14)


public static ArrayList<String> bestDirectPrice(ArrayList<String> flightList,String city1, String city2) {
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> Price = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i=0; i<flightList.size(); i++) {
    list = directFlights(flightList, city1, city2);
    Price.add(getPrice(list.get(i)));

}
return Price;
```

I've been searching online for a solution, so I'm pretty sure the problem is that the array is too small, but i'm still not sure how to fix it. I'm trying to get the upper part of code to take just the numbers out of the array and put them in a new one.

```
ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>(); //Array with list of flights
test.add("Orlando#DesMoines#194.88");
test.add("Portland#Orlando#287.74");
test.add("Buffalo#Boston#299.52"); 
test.add("Buffalo#Portland#264.80"); 
test.add("Chicago#Buffalo#223.56");

System.out.println(bestDirectPrice(test,"Buffalo","Orlando"));
```

And here are the other methods I'm calling.

```
public static String getPrice(String price) { //Takes flight description, which is a string, as a parameter and returns price of flight
String[] sArray = price.split("#", -1);
String newPrice = "";
for (int i = 0; i<1; i++)       
    newPrice = sArray[2];
return newPrice;
}

public static ArrayList<String> directFlights(ArrayList<String> flightList, String city1, String city2) { // Method to create array list containing every direct flight from city1 to city 2
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i=0; i<flightList.size(); i++){
    String city2a = getDestinationCity(flightList.get(i));
    String city1a = getOriginationCity(flightList.get(i));
    if (city1a.equals(city1) && city2a.equals(city2)) {
        list.add(flightList.get(i));
    }
}
return list;
}
```

I've been stuck on this for awhile so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1   
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)   
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)  
at pa6.FlightFinder.bestDirectPrice(FlightFinder.java:117)  
at pa6.FlightFinder.main(FlightFinder.java:14)
```

Comment: A nice stack trace would help a lot here I believe.

Comment: Sorry I'm still pretty new to java. What's a stack trace?

Comment: @Scheids `stacktrace` is complete exception you are getting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: Yes, and this error output might lead you to the exact line where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop is with respect to flightList, not list.
In every iteration you're reassigning a new value to list rather than adding a new element.

Try changing

```
for (int i=0; i<flightList.size(); i++) {
    list = directFlights(flightList, city1, city2);
    Price.add(getPrice(list.get(i)));

}
```

to

```
list = directFlights(flightList, city1, city2);
for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
    Price.add(getPrice(list.get(i)));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed!

Answer (score 3):

Please look into these two blocks

Looping until `i < flightList.size()`

But `getPrice(list.get(i)` is using index from above but on different list

```
for (int i=0; i<flightList.size(); i++) {
    list = directFlights(flightList, city1, city2);
    Price.add(getPrice(list.get(i)));

}
```

Inside Method , `directFlights()`

List is created using below condition, meaning `size of list will always be less than or equal to size of flightList`.

But above `getPrice(list.get(i)` is using indexing from parent list (flightList).

```
if (city1a.equals(city1) && city2a.equals(city2)) {
        list.add(flightList.get(i));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot more sense!

Comment: @Scheids this is something that now you can debug and trace it, because at runtime what is the data, what is size of both list, we cannot know